CustomTkinter App Keeps the First Instance and Takes PC Memory
````
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Button, PhotoImage
import time
import subprocess
import traceback
import sys
import logging
import os
import sys

def resource_path(relative_path):

    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)



def start_soncalisandikkat():
    script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'SONCALISANDIKKAT.py')
    
    if os.path.exists(script_path):
        # Windows için özel işlem ve terminal bayraklarıyla çalıştır
        if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows
            subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path])
        else:  # MacOS ve Linux
            subprocess.Popen(["python3", script_path])
    else:
        print(f"{script_path} dosyası bulunamadı!")
# Log ayarları
log_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "error_log.txt")
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_path, level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', filemode='a')
# Sahte bir API çağrısı simülasyonu
def mock_api_call(email, password):
    print(f"API çağrısı yapılıyor: Email: {email}, Şifre: {password}")
    time.sleep(2)  # Simülasyon için 2 saniye bekliyoruz
    if email == "a" and password == "1":
        print("Giriş başarılı, API'den doğrulandı.")
        return True
    else:
        print("Giriş başarısız, yanlış bilgiler.")
        return False

# Pencereyi yavaşça saydamlaştırarak kapatmak
def smooth_transition_to_dashboard():
    alpha = window.attributes("-alpha")
    if alpha > 0:
        alpha -= 0.05
        window.attributes("-alpha", alpha)
        window.after(50, smooth_transition_to_dashboard)
    else:
        successful_login()


def successful_login():
    try:
        print("SONCALISANDIKKAT.py başlatılıyor...")
        
        script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'SONCALISANDIKKAT.py')
        print(f"Tam dosya yolu: {script_path}")
        logging.info(f"Tam dosya yolu: {script_path}")
        start_soncalisandikkat()  
        # Dosya mevcut mu kontrol et
        if os.path.exists(script_path):
            print(f"{script_path} bulundu, çalıştırılıyor...")
            logging.info(f"{script_path} bulundu, çalıştırılıyor...")
            
            # Login penceresini kapatalım
            window.destroy()
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"{script_path} dosyası bulunamadı!")
            
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"SONCALISANDIKKAT.py başlatılırken bir hata oluştu:\n{traceback.format_exc()}"
        log_error(error_message)  # Hata mesajını hem loga hem terminale yazdır



        
# Hata loglama fonksiyonu
def log_error(message):
    """Hataları hem terminale hem de log dosyasına yazdırır."""
    print(message)
    logging.error(message)


# Giriş kontrolü ve dashboard'a geçiş
def login():
    email = entry_1.get()
    password = entry_2.get()

    # Mock API çağrısı yapıyoruz
    if mock_api_call(email, password):
        smooth_transition_to_dashboard()  # Giriş başarılı ise smooth geçiş

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1366x768")
#window.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")
window.attributes("-alpha", 1.0)  # Pencerenin tam opak olarak başlamasını sağlıyoruz
window.configure(bg="#EBDFD7")
window.title("Okulistik Uploader")
window.iconbitmap(resource_path("Images/favicon.ico"))
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg="#FAD4B8",
    height=768,
    width=1366,
    bd=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief="ridge"
)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

image_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\image_1.png"))
canvas.create_image(181.0, 424.1875, image=image_image_1)

image_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\image_2.png"))
canvas.create_image(957.3916625976562, 383.5093688964844, image=image_image_2)

image_image_3 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\image_3.png"))
canvas.create_image(319.0, 386.0, image=image_image_3)

image_image_4 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\image_4.png"))
canvas.create_image(248.0, 176.1875, image=image_image_4)

canvas.create_text(152.0, 239.0, anchor="nw", text="Email", fill="#333333", font=("Gilroy Medium", 13 * -1))

entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(319.5, 283.0, image=entry_image_1)
entry_1 = Entry(bd=0, bg="#FFFFFF", fg="#000716", highlightthickness=0)
entry_1.place(x=156.0, y=263.0, width=327.0, height=38.0)

canvas.create_text(362.0, 399.0, anchor="nw", text="Forgot Password?", fill="#AE4700", font=("Gilroy Medium", 14 * -1))

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\\button_1.png"))
button_1 = Button(
    image=button_image_1,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=login,  # Giriş işlemine yönlendiriyoruz
    relief="flat"
)
button_1.place(x=152.0, y=447.99749755859375, width=335.0, height=32.0)

canvas.create_text(152.0, 319.0, anchor="nw", text="Password", fill="#333333", font=("Gilroy Medium", 13 * -1))

entry_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\entry_2.png"))
entry_bg_2 = canvas.create_image(319.5, 363.0, image=entry_image_2)
entry_2 = Entry(bd=0, bg="#FFFFFF", fg="#000716", highlightthickness=0, show='*')  # Şifre girişini gizlemek için
entry_2.place(x=156.0, y=343.0, width=327.0, height=38.0)

image_image_5 = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("LoginResimleri\image_5.png"))
canvas.create_image(308.0, 529.1875, image=image_image_5)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()


So, I tried fixing it like this, but no good output. Still the same.

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """PyInstaller ile çalışırken statik dosyaların dinamik yolunu ayarlar."""
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

def start_soncalisandikkat():
    script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'SONCALISANDIKKAT.py')
    
    if os.path.exists(script_path):
        # Bağımsız bir süreç olarak çalıştır
        if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows
            subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
        else:  # MacOS ve Linux
            subprocess.Popen(["python3", script_path])
    else:
        print(f"{script_path} dosyası bulunamadı!")

def successful_login():
    try:
        print("SONCALISANDIKKAT.py başlatılıyor...")
        
        
        start_soncalisandikkat()
        
        
        if window.winfo_exists():  # Pencere mevcutsa kontrol edin
            window.destroy()
        
        
        os._exit(0)
        
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"SONCALISANDIKKAT.py başlatılırken bir hata oluştu:\n{traceback.format_exc()}"
        log_error(error_message)  

    def resource_path(relative_path): """PyInstaller ile çalışırken statik dosyaların dinamik yolunu ayarlar.""" base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))) return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

def start_soncalisandikkat(): script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), 'SONCALISANDIKKAT.py')

if os.path.exists(script_path):
    # Bağımsız bir süreç olarak çalıştır
    if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows
        subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    else:  # MacOS ve Linux
        subprocess.Popen(["python3", script_path])
else:
    print(f"{script_path} dosyası bulunamadı!")
def successful_login(): try: print("SONCALISANDIKKAT.py başlatılıyor...")

    start_soncalisandikkat()


    if window.winfo_exists():  # Pencere mevcutsa kontrol edin
        window.destroy()

    os._exit(0)

except Exception as e:
    error_message = f"SONCALISANDIKKAT.py başlatılırken bir hata oluştu:\n{traceback.format_exc()}"
    log_error(error_message)  
````

Guys this all I've done. tried my best. Also, is my use of CustomTkinter is bad practice? Can it be used like this or should I rework the whole structure to make like a single folder and layers between login and dashboard? At this moment, I have login.py and SONCALISANDIKKAT.py(dashboard). So it closes login.py after successfull login and opens the dashboard.
I would be extremly happy, if I can get constructive response. I gave a lot for this one.I might need to restart the whole process due to wrong use of Tkinter libraries.. I don't know guys please help...

Where is the customtkinter app? Why are you using a subprocess here? I assume your customtkinter app is defined in a different file. As for the GUI, we close/destroy windows, not files. If you want to close the Tk window and open the Ctk window next, it is possible. Explain how your program should work.

So I have a login.py and dashboard.py(soncalisandikkat.py). When Running the code it all works fine. I can login and it will go to second py and vice versa. When I use pyinstaller even though I put the folders inside. I stuck at login screen even if the dynamic folder of second py is found.

You can import the code from dashboard.py into login.py and create a new window after destroying the Tk window. Why is the subprocess even here?

I know I may have bad practice :)  I reworked the code. Now, I made the code on a single page with switching frames. What I found is working with subprocess or opening other files is not too good when you want to make your project an app or an exe. Although I've managed to make the functionality. It still has bugs and performance issues. To cut to the chase, I figured using one .py file is way better than other practices. When you use it as an app with subprocess etc... The process keeps running.  If it is possible please explain your reaction to the subprocess :) I want to learn. Much love

When you run subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path]), you are relying on the fact that your user has Python installed on their system (and has also installed customtkinter). What could be wrong. To make it work (as two separate GUIs), you can convert the customtkinter program into an executable. Then run it using a subprocess without "python".

But this is usually done with: 1) single root window (tkinter.Tk or customtkinter.CTk) with multiple top-level windows (tkinter.Toplevel or customtkinter.CTkToplevel); 2) single window that changes widgets based on user actions.
No need to create new processes.
